# Check if a player is blocking

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is is possible to check if a player is blocking? If so, how is it done? It didn't have any stat that seemed right on the wiki, and I didn't see one when I hit tab on "/scoreboard add derp". Thanks for any help you give.

Comment: [SethBling](https://www.youtube.com/user/sethbling) wrote a [Bukkit plugin](http://sethbling.com/BlingCombat) that can tell when (and for how long) someone is blocking, so it's definitely possible when using Bukkit.  Don't think you can do it in vanilla, at least not easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to check that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, at least in 1.8.3 and under. I'm not sure if they will add it, but you can get a mod for it.